# Українські словники у формі відкритих даних?

Tags: resource-request, словники

Чи зустрічав хтось українські словники (орфографічний, тлумачний, синонімічний, абревіатур та інші) у відкритих форматах (txt, csv, json, xml, markdown), що доступні для вільного завантаження та розповсюдження, в тому числі в комерційних цілях або як частини сторонніх програмних продуктів?

Я знайшов [електронні проекти](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/LSlist/) Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України, але це електронні версії словників, а не словники у формі відкритих даних.

Чи є обмеження щодо вільного копіювання та розповсюдження матеріалів із словників, що доступні на сайті фонду НАН України, якщо вони будуть переведені в формат відкритих даних?

Comment: Прибрав тег "нан", бо більше п'яти тегів не можна поставити. Потім об'єднаємо "словники" і "ukrainian-dictionaries", і звільниться слот.

Comment: Ось на GitHub є  [великий електронний словник української мови (ВЕСУМ)](https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk).  `Словник містить слова та їхні парадигми з відповідними тегами, а також іншу інформацію,
зокрема:
* додаткові теги: slang, rare, bad...
* пропоновані заміни для покручів
* зв’язок між базовими та порівняльними формами прикметників

Для всіх файлів в data/dict цей проект генерує всі можливі словоформи з тегами частин мови
за допомогою правил афіксів у каталозі data/affix.`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Під [відкритими даними](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96) мається на увазі один або обидва з таких аспектів:

- Ліцензування: [вільна ліцензія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F) або взагалі [суспільне надбання](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F).
- Формат: [машиночитаний](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_data) або принаймні такий, що його легко (можливо) [спарсити](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7).

Єдині проекти під відкритою ліцензією, що я знаю:

- **[Український Вікісловник](//uk.wiktionary.org/)** — *СС BY-SA 3.0*.
- **[Великий електронний словник української мови (ВЕСУМ)](//github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/blob/master/doc/announcement.md)** — *GPL v3* <sub>(не плутати з [Великим тлумачним словником сучасної української мови (ВТССУМ)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) видавництва «Перун» за редакцією Бусела)</sub>.
- **[«Цифрові лексикографічні системи української мови», або «mphdict»](//github.com/LinguisticAndInformationSystems/mphdict/wiki)** (див. [окрему відповідь](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2780)) — програмна сировина під *MIT*, бази даних під *ODbL* <sub>(бази даних на основі «Етимологічного словника української мови», чи отримано дозвіл правовласників словника, мені невідомо)</sub>.
- **[Український тональний словник](//github.com/lang-uk/tone-dict-uk)** — *?*.
- <sub>Корпуси і набори даних:</sub>

  - <sub>[Браунський корпус української мови](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus), а також його [NER-анотація](//github.com/lang-uk/ner-uk).</sub>
  - <sub>[ua-gazetteers (набір різноманітних колекцій даних українською мовою)](//github.com/lang-uk/ua-gazetteers) та інші [проекти](//github.com/lang-uk/) [lang-uk](//github.com/lang-uk/lang-uk.github.io).</sub>
  - <sub>[Статистика українських діалектів](//dialectstat.wikispaces.com).</sub>

Всі інші проекти, в тому числі словники НАНУ, УМІФ тощо, здебільшого, на жаль, мають «традиційну» (не вільну) або взагалі не зазначену (тобто що власники в будь-який момент можуть позиватися з будь-якого приводу) ліцензію. Деякі з проектів, що оцифровують видані словники, можливо, самі є порушниками авторського права — але це не означає можливість вільного користування їхніми даними. Можливо, варто написати листа в НАНУ/УМІФ/тощо з метою з'ясувати чи пом'якщити ліцензію деяких проектів — але, за моїм особистим прогнозом, навряд чи вони будуть зацікавлені в повному відкритті матеріалів (формальному переведенні їх у стан суспільного надбання чи під вільну ліцензію), в найкращому випадку Ви отримаєте усну обіцянку непереслідування.

Щодо переведення даних в машиночитаний формат — то це, на мою думку, найменша проблема.

Comment: Щодо інституту УМІФ НАН України та його робіт:
Всі продукти академічного інституту УМІФу НАН України розроблені за державний кошт, а такі продукти, як ІЛС «Словники України» та Український лінгвістичний корпус УМІФу НАН України віднесено до наукових об'єктів НАН України, що становлять національне надбання, на які щорічно виділяються державою України кошти.

Comment: Також звертаємо увагу, що до цього лінгвістичного корпусу УМІФу НАН України користувачі, громадяни України, взагалі не мають доступу (питання про існування цього національного надбання?), так само, як і до останньої версії ІЛС «Словники України» 4.1: система розроблена під одну пропрієтарну ОС, міжплатформенна веб-версія відсутня.

Comment: Також ще в 2004 році директору цієї інституції вдалось провернути аферу з віднесення до наукових об'єктів НАН України, що становлять національне надбання, ряд інформаційних об'єктів, в тому числі інструментальний комп’ютерний комплекс "Фундаментальний академічний Словник української мови". Як ми знаємо перший том цієї праці вийшов аж в 2010 році, а зараз ми маємо аж 7 томів цієї праці. Виходить, що в далекому 2004 році до наукових об'єктів НАН України, що становлять національне надбання, було віднесено повітря.

Comment: В той же час інститутом УМІФ до сих пір не надано повного доступу  до словника (http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl), хоча директор інституту УМІФ в багатьох інтерв’ю та публікаціях вже давно заявляє, що цей словник готовий і він є національним надбанням, а гроші з бюджету продовжують надходити: https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/UA-2017-03-03-000402-a

Comment: Наявність та осмислення цієї інформації демонструє хибність думки, щодо можливості про щось домовитись з директором УМІФу НАН України Широковим В.А. На нашу думку потрібно ці питання піднімати в суспільстві, обговорювати їх якомога ширшим колом.

Answer (score 10):

"Цифрові лексикографічні системи української мови" (mphdict)

Проект містить:

1. SQLite бази даних граматичних словників, що зберігають інформацію про слова, всі словозмінні класи, властиві їм квазіфлексії, акцентуаційні класи та інші дані;
2. SQLite бази даних словників синонімів;
3. SQLite базу даних етимологічного словника української мови, що була сформована в освітніх цілях на основі томів 1–6 Етимологічного словника української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України: була розроблена оригінальна структура БД та розроблена веб-система її відображення. Ми не надаємо доступ до твору Етимологічний словник української мови Інституту мовознавства ім. О.О. Потебні НАН України, а в освітніх цілях демонструємо можливість роботи зі складноструктурованою БД етимологічної системи, яка є нашою оригінальною розробкою;
4. бібліотеку роботи з базами (mphdict project) та веб-систему словників (mphweb project).

Всі бази даних та алгоритми систем є відкритими та надаються до використання та модифікації відповідно до потреб користувача.

Проект [розміщено на GitHub](//github.com/LinguisticAndInformationSystems/mphdict) під ліцензією MIT (самі бази даних розповсюджуються за ліцензією Open Database License (ODbL) 1.0). Система може бути розгорнута як у Windows середовищі, так і в Linux. Будь-хто, системний адміністратор у школі або університеті, може розгорнути систему у внутрішній мережі закладу.

- [Про систему](https://github.com/LinguisticAndInformationSystems/mphdict/wiki)
- [Як встановити Систему словників на домашньому комп’ютері з ОС Windows](https://github.com/LinguisticAndInformationSystems/mphdict/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%E2%80%99%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96-%D0%B7-%D0%9E%D0%A1-Windows)
- [Фейсбук сторінка проекту](https://www.facebook.com/USofTrod-180689769033511/)

Comment: УМІФ НАН України [невдоволений](http://ulif.org.ua/page/pro-porushiennia-avtors-kikh-prav) (ще [посилання](//www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=458469247880573&id=307858899608276)) використанням його матеріалів (можливо, [вже подав позов до суду](//www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=458469247880573&id=307858899608276&comment_id=464993033894861&reply_comment_id=465021600558671)).

Comment: Інформація щодо суперечки uSofTrod з інститутом Національної Академії Наук України УМІФ НАН України.
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=458469247880573&id=307858899608276
uSofTrod надав всі свої аргументи на користь того, що їх розробка є оригінальною, а звинувачення УМІФу безпідставними у коментарях до вищезазначеного посту. Але адміністратори цієї сторінки від УМІФу їх видалили. Тому uSofTrod опублікував їх на своїй сторінці і готовий до будь якого розвитку подій:
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=390742814716688&id=100013429187310

Comment: Також, в світлі вищезазначених подій було проведено роботу з дослідження "наукової" діяльності директора УМІФу НАН України та деяких співробітників цього інституту: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=390745144716455&id=100013429187310

Comment: Я читав ці аргументи. Перепрошую, але, хоч я нічого не знаю про НАНУ (може, в них самих рильце в пушку) і не є професійним юристом, але мені здається, в даному випадку вони формально праві — Ви самі зазначаєте, що використовували матеріали ЕСУМ, власником якого не є. Та, навіть припистимо, що НАНУ неправі, а Ви праві — я просто зазначив, що така суперечка триває, і допоки вона офіційно не вирішена на Вашу користь, статус цієї розробки незрозумілий.

Comment: Ви безперечно праві, щодо офіційного вирішення. Але ми беремося прогнозувати, що це питання УМІФ педалювати не буде, і саме через те, що прекрасно розуміє, чого цей інститут власником є, а чого ні.

Answer (score 3):

Ось [тут](http://fex.net/#!183604890500) (*гниле посилання*) є база даних слів української мови у форматі SQLite. Усі дані розпарсено з сайту slovnyk.ua в якості студентського університетського проекту.

В українській мові є 10 частин мови. Для кожної з них створено окрему таблицю, а також окремі таблиці для вставних слів та дієприслівників, хоча вони не є окремими частинами мови. Відмінювані частини (іменники, прикметники, дієслова, займенники, числівники) містять також інформацію про свій рід, число, відмінок, часову форму та дієвідміну (якщо є).

Список таблиць у БД:

- chastki
- chislivniki
- dieprislivniki
- dieslova
- imeniki
- prikmetniki
- primeniki
- prislivniki
- spolychniki
- vihyki
- vstavni_slova
- zaimeniki

Стосовно ліцензії - ця база даних вільна для розповсюдження.

Comment: Здається, посилання перестало працювати.

Comment: До речі, про це: «стосовно ліцензії — ця база даних вільна для розповсюдження» — а ліценція slovnyk.ua дозволяла його парсити (і вільно розповсюджувати результати парсингу)?

Comment: Цікаво, хто продовжує плюсувати цю відповідь, незважаючи на те, що **через застарілість посилання** вона вже нічого не дає?